# Generic Graph Class using a Generic Vertex class as it's data

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a generic graph data structure in C#. I am having difficulty trying to constrain the graph to be of my custom generic vertex type, but allowing the vertex to be of any type of data.

I want to be able to add a vertex to the graph by specifying the data that the vertex will hold. My vertex class looks like this (ellipsis replacing irrelevant code):

```
public class VertexGeneric<T> where T : class
{
    public T data;
    public int key;
    public VertexGeneric(int keyIn, T dataIn)
    {
        data = dataIn;
        key = keyIn;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If I write the graph class like the following then adding the vertex to my dictionary on the eighth line breaks compilation because even though T is constrained to be a VertexGeneric, and the newVertex I'm attempting to add to the dictionary is a VertexGeneric, the compiler doesn't see them as the same.

```
public class GraphGeneric<T, U> where T : VertexGeneric<U> where U : class
{
    Dictionary<int, T> vertices;
    ...
    public int AddVertex(U newVertexData)
    {
        VertexGeneric<U> newVertex = new VertexGeneric<U>(key, newVertexData);
        vertices.Add(key, newVertex);   
        return key;
    }
    ...
}
```

If I instead write the graph class so that I'm dealing only with the data type T that will be the data stored in the vertex, then I cannot declare my dictionary in the same way. The third line here where I'm declaring the dictionary will break compilation.

```
public class GraphGeneric<T> where T : class
{
    Dictionary<int, VertexGeneric<T>> vertices;
    ...
    public int AddVertex(T newVertexData)
    {
        VertexGeneric<T> newVertex = new VertexGeneric<T>(key, newVertexData);
        vertices.Add(key, newVertex );  
        return key;
    }
    ...
}
```

I cannot seem to find a solution to this that my compiler finds acceptable. Again, my goal is to be able to create a graph object and add vertices to it by passing in the data the vertex will contain to the AddVertex function within GraphGeneric. How do I make this happen? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you add a smallest compilable example that will break? Because right now, there are basic errors in it like your Vertex constructor taking two parameters, one of them not even a valid variable. Fix those first and post the code.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example there is no type `U`, change it to

```
VertexGeneric<T> newVertex = new VertexGeneric<T>(key, newVertexData);
```

The reason your first example doesn't work is that the dictionary contains `T` vaules, but you are only providing `VertexGeneric<U>` instances, which are supertypes of `T`. This is similar to the following non-generic example

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add(1, new object());
```